# php framework clevercore

Tags: php, mvc, framework, документация, library

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знаком с php-фреймворком clevercore? Где можно найти на него документацию? Гугл не помогает

Comment: На packagist ничего нет с таким именем, или фреймворк старый и не использует composer, или это внутрення разработка какой-то кампании, такое часто бывает, в таком случае, если там есть composer, можно глянуть на каких пакетах она базируется.

Comment: А что может быть с такой файловой структурой? http://joxi.ru/Grqb1yeHGajJRm

Comment: С той инфо что на картинке склоняюсь больше что это действительно самопис, в проекте и в самом деле нет composer? Может какая-то неизвестная crm...